# Subsequent calls to WMIC return a localdatetime with a deviating timezone

Tags: windows, time, wmic

### The problem

In our company environment we use several batch files which use WMIC to retrieve the current time. Usually to print it to log files, but also to include the timestamp in a file name.

Starting with Windows 10 - we do not remember seeing this behavior on Windows 7 - we experienced that some of our log file parsers (they create some nice graphs for evaluation) seemed to draw weird stuff. After some research we found out, that for short time periods, the call to WMIC returns a *different timestamp*.

This is how we call WMIC, and what it returns.

```
C:\> WMIC.exe OS Get localdatetime /value
LocalDateTime=20191114112607.134000+060
```

Now we made an experiment and called WMIC every second for a larger period of time. Here is an excerpt of the resulting timestamps:

```
20191114112607.134000+060
20191114122608.394000+120
20191114122609.687000+120
[...]
20191114123105.161000+120
20191114123106.431000+120
20191114113107.672000+060
```

We live in a region in MEZ timezone, that is UTC+1. This is why we expect the timestamps with the `+060` minute indication. We also do not expect it to change, unless twice a year, that is when day light savings time switches to MESZ (UTC+2) and vice versa.

As you can see in the timestamps above: For almost exactly 5 minutes, WMIC returns the `+120` timestamp.

### The analysis

I also logged the output of some other calls, to check whether this is a global Windows problem or rather a wmic behavior. All seems to be a sort of (buggy?) behavior of WMIC.

All functions/programs and even another WMIC call returned the expected time. This is my script

```perl
while ($true) {
    Get-Date -Format G
    Get-TimeZone

    $timeservers | ForEach-Object {
        $server = $_
        w32tm.exe /stripchart /computer:$server /dataonly /samples:1 | Out-Default
    }

    cmd.exe /c date /T | Out-Default
    cmd.exe /c time /T | Out-Default

    WMIC.exe Path Win32_LocalTime Get /Format:value | Out-Default

    # All 'correct' except:
    WMIC.exe OS Get localdatetime /value | Out-Default

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

The output of the above script shows that only the `OS Get localdatetime` call is returning the 'wrong' timestamp. We have searched the System and Application event log for entries that could tell us why this happens, but there were no entries logged. I also checked the Task Scheduler if some action was scheduled to run when this happens, but nothing.

**Registry time zone information**

```
C:\>reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
    Bias    REG_DWORD    0xffffffc4
    DaylightBias    REG_DWORD    0xffffffc4
    DaylightName    REG_SZ    @tzres.dll,-321
    DaylightStart    REG_BINARY    00000300050002000000000000000000
    DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled    REG_DWORD    0x0
    StandardBias    REG_DWORD    0x0
    StandardName    REG_SZ    @tzres.dll,-322
    StandardStart    REG_BINARY    00000A00050003000000000000000000
    TimeZoneKeyName    REG_SZ    W. Europe Standard Time
    ActiveTimeBias    REG_DWORD    0xffffffc4
```

### The questions

- Can someone explain the behavior?
- What could influence the outcome of WMIC?
- Would you think this is a sort of bug?
- What other analysis could be done to narrow this down?

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1. Have you tried disabling Windows Time Service and reproducing the issue? 2. Please run `reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation` to dump timezone setting stored in registry and share them

Comment: I added the registry settings to my question. Still need to try out with disable time service because I was ooo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is now a known Windows Bug.

Internally there is a global variable which caches the DST offset which keeps its value for 5 minutes. After 5 minutes the value goes away which leaves you with a jumping local time.

This logic was being used in RS5/1809 but not in 19H1 or in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Workarounds:

- Boot the machines often enough so that LocalDateTime and LastBootUpTime cannot end up with different timezones when the machine is running for a longer time
- Setting the InstallDate to the time of the last reboot using a script that runs at startup should also avoid the issue